# How StringBuffer behaves When Passing Char as argument to its Overloaded Constructor?

Tags: java

```
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer('A');
    System.out.println("sb = " + sb.toString());
    sb.append("Hello");
    System.out.println("sb = " + sb.toString());
```

Output:

> sb =
>
> sb = Hello

But if i pass a String instead of character, it appends to Hello .
Why is this strange behavior with char ?

Comment: Please read the JavaDoc of the constructor you're using. It tells you what happens.

Answer (score 6):

There is no constructor which accepts a `char`. You end up with the [`int` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#StringBuffer(int)) due to Java automatically converting your `char` to an `int`, thus specifying the initial capacity.

```
/**
 * Constructs a string buffer with no characters in it and
 * the specified initial capacity.
 *
 * @param      capacity  the initial capacity.
 * @exception  NegativeArraySizeException  if the <code>capacity</code>
 *               argument is less than <code>0</code>.
 */
public StringBuffer(int capacity) {
    super(capacity);
}
```

Cf. this minimal example:

```
public class StringBufferTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer('a');
        System.out.println(buf.capacity());
        System.out.println((int) 'a');
        StringBuffer buf2 = new StringBuffer('b');
        System.out.println(buf2.capacity());
        System.out.println((int) 'b');
    }
}
```

Output:

```
97
97
98
98
```

Whereas

```
StringBuffer buf3 = new StringBuffer("a");
System.out.println(buf3.capacity());
```

Results in an initial capacity of `17`.

You might have confused `char` with [`CharSequence`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) (for which there is indeed a constructor), but these are two completely different things.

Answer (score 0):

U have used below mentioned constructor.

> public StringBuffer(int capacity)
>
> Constructs a string buffer with no characters in it and the specified initial capacity.
>
> Parameters:
> capacity - the initial capacity.

see the [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) u don't have any constructor which takes char input param.