# String buffer not printing 'Character'

Tags: java, stringbuffer

I checked the following code found that instead of  printing A123 it is priting 123 .

Can some one explain what's going on here.

```
 public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuffer sb = null;
    sb = new StringBuffer('A');
    sb.append('1');
    sb.append('2');
    sb.append('3');
    System.out.println(sb);//Printing 123
}
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30819945/how-stringbuffer-behaves-when-passing-char-as-argument-to-its-overloaded-constru.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling the [constructor that specifys the capacity](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#StringBuffer-int-). Try this

```
sb = new StringBuffer("A");
```

Comment: Then it should be a compile time error.

Comment: @Show No, there is a constructor taking an `int`.

Comment: no the char literal 'A' is interpreted as an int

Comment: I got it please edit your post and put "A"  as charcter 'A'

Comment: why when you know that wont work?

Answer (score 1):

You encountered  `int` to `char` conversion.

You are invoking the constructor  [StringBuffer(int capacity)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#StringBuffer(int)).

```
public StringBuffer(int capacity) {
        super(capacity);
    }
```

Since you passing the char, it converted to int value (ASCII value) and taking as capacity.

Comment: Good explanation except for calling the UTF-16 code unit (`char`) an ASCII value.